# What is the command to check the version of the postgresql jdbc driver on Linux command line?

Tags: linux, postgresql, jdbc, driver

I am working on Linux server with PostgreSQL that is installed through the command line.

How could I check the version of the **PostgreSQL JDBC Driver** using Linux command line?

I use this command  `psql -V` and it shows the PostgreSQL version `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.24`, but I need the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver version. What is the command the should I use?

Comment: -V prints the psql version, NOT the PostgreSQL database version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run:

```
java -jar /path/to/driver.jar
```

it will report its version.

Obviously you need to replace `/path/to/driver.jar` with the correct location where you stored the driver when you downloaded it.

By default the file name itself contains the version. So if you downloaded `postgresql-42.2.19.jar` then it's highly likely its version is 42.2.19

---

As a side note: `psql -V` prints the version of the command line tool. That's not necessarily the same version as the server.

Comment: I am on Linux server that I can access only through the command line , how can I find the jar of the driver? because it was already installed on the server when I got it.

Comment: Well, then you need to find the jar file somewhere. There is no default location. But how to find a file in a Linux system is a completely different question.

Comment: I found more than jar file for PostgreSQL how I know which one is installed? Binary file `./.m2/repository/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc4/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar ` `ontop/jdbc/postgresql-42.2.6.jar`

Comment: Again: you don't "install" a JDBC driver - you just use it. Those are all inside the local Maven repository. Which you are actually using depends on your Maven projects.

Answer (score 2):

From Java, you can use code like this:

```java
java.sql.Driver d = new org.postgresql.Driver();
System.out.println(d.getMajorVersion() + "." + d.getMinorVersion());
```

See [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/Driver.html) for details.